# Compartilhar base de dados na nuvem (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, cloud

É possível compartilhar um banco de dados (PostgreSQL) na nuvem, como o Dropbox, Google Drive?

Quero compartilhar meu banco de dados, inicialmente para acessar a partir de diferentes ambientes, apenas para iniciar um novo aplicativo.

É possível em qualquer serviço de nuvem, como devo proceder para isso?

Existe alguma base de dados em serviço de nuvem gratuita para PostgreSQL?

Desde já agradeço !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um serviço de armazenamento e compartilhamento de arquivos como o Google Drive e Dropbox não é suficiente, pois o PostgreSQL em si é um servidor. Ele precisa estar sendo executado em uma máquina que aceite acessos dos clientes na porta 5432 (por padrão).

O máximo que você pode fazer nesse caso é gerar um arquivo com o conteúdo de seu banco PostgreSQL com uma ferramenta de dump como o [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) e compartilhar esse arquivo via Dropbox ou Google Drive para que seja carregado por outras pessoas em seus PostgreSQL particulares.

> Existe alguma base de dados em serviço de nuvem gratuita para PostgreSQL?

Experimente o [ElephantSQL](https://www.elephantsql.com/), eles oferecem um plano gratuito para bases pequenas e com poucos acessos concorrentes.

Todos os grandes serviços de computação em nuvem, como [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/), [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/), e [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com) também oferecem servidores Postgres. Como na resposta do @Shura16, eu também gostaria de citar o [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), sobretudo porque eles contribuem bastante no desenvolvimento do PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

A base de dados em si não, normalmente as bases de dados são restritas para acesso local.
Mas se criar uma API (por exemplo REST) por usar serviços como [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).